# How to debug crash in default-priority dispatch queue of iOS app?

Tags: ios, crash, grand-central-dispatch

My App, distributed as Ad-Hoc Build, crashes on some devices with crash log like this.

```
Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority`
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3551d296 CFRelease + 14
1   MyApp                           0x00145dae 0xdf000 + 421294
2   MyApp                           0x00145f6a 0xdf000 + 421738
3   MyApp                           0x0010259c 0xdf000 + 144796
4   MyApp                           0x000e36ca 0xdf000 + 18122
5   libdispatch.dylib             0x34461c52 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
6   libdispatch.dylib             0x34464810 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
7   libsystem_c.dylib             0x32991df4 _pthread_wqthread + 288
8   libsystem_c.dylib             0x32991cc8 start_wqthread + 0
```

I have no idea of what clue I can get from this log. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by turning the addresses on the stack into symbol names that you can find in your code.  Apple has a tech note about it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html